# Fix already commited CRLF in git

Tags: git, newline

I have set git to `core.autocrlf = true`. However it seems there are already commited files that have CRLF inside the repository. When I modify such a file, then git seems to assume that no implicit conversion is necessary and as a result `git diff` shows those annoying `^M` at the end of each line. For other files which are checked out as CRLF but commited as LF I do not see any `^M` at the end of changed lines. How can I fix the problematic files in my repository?

I do not want to use solutions that use `git filter-branch` since I do not want to rewrite the history. I want to create add a new commit that fixes the problematic files. Preferably I would like to fix individual files and not everything at once.

Comment: I'd skip using core.autocrlf. It can be veeery tricky... plus it's the old implementation to solve EOL errors. Try with gitattributes https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes (read about text)

Answer (score 1):

Use your favorite text editor to change all CRLF to LF. Any good programming editor or IDE has an option for which EOL sequence to use. Change it to Unix style and reformat all files in your project. Then make a commit.

Comment: This basically works, but there are two little issues. If you can update your answer I will mark it as correct.
1. I wanted to change CRLF to LF not to CR.
2. After I made the commit I still needed to reset the changed file in the working directory, so the checked out version has CRLF again. I did this by running the following two commands:
 `git rm --cached -- <filename>` followed by `git reset --hard`.

Comment: @lanoxx What is the reason for having CRLF in the working copy?

Comment: Under Windows it is the recommended mode of git to set `core.autocrlf=true`, which commits LF into the repository and checks out platform dependend line endings. Thus it well checkout LF on Linux and Mac, but CRLF on Windows.